# How to write the following SQL statement in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i just got into pandas few days ago. I would like to try what i used to do with SQL, and try it with pandas dataframe without using pandasql, can anyone give me some clue with it?

```
> SELECT TOP 1 col FROM ( SELECT 
>     col AS col, 
>     LEN(col) AS length,
>     CAST(LEFT(col, 20) AS numeric(20,0)) AS col_p1,
>     (CASE
>         WHEN LEN(col) > 20 THEN CAST(RIGHT(col,LEN(col) - 20) AS numeric(20,0))
>     END) AS col_p2  FROM table_a WHERE SIGN(CAST(LEFT(col,2) AS SMALLINT)) = 1 ORDER BY length DESC, col_p1 DESC, col_p2 DESC )
```

Comment: not so difficult, but need to see your input data that your running your query on pleas see [ask] and [mcve] also I think your sql could be better written with a CTE but that's another question all together!

Comment: i got a list of int id, need to find the largest id. i've got my problem settle, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your query to a tree and the go from leaves up to the root node(aka relational algebra tree). Here's what I mean:

1. You begin with the nested table

```sql
SELECT [COLUMNS]  FROM table_a WHERE [CONDITION] ORDER BY [CRITERIA]
```

2. And then you go on and select only the interesting rows:

```sql
WHERE SIGN(CAST(LEFT(col,2) AS SMALLINT)) = 1 

# equivalent to  mask = df['col'].apply(lambda val: int(val[:2]) > 0 )
# and then you apply the mask to the dataframe
```

3. After this step, you go and create new columns, concatenate and rename them:

```sql
CAST(LEFT(col, 20) AS numeric(20,0)) AS col_p1,
     (CASE
         WHEN LEN(col) > 20 THEN CAST(RIGHT(col,LEN(col) - 20) AS numeric(20,0))
     END) AS col_p2


# for those 2, you can generate a numpy array and add it to the dataframe


# and then you rename your columns :
#      df.columns = [...]
```

4. For the ordering, you can use `sort_values`

```sql
ORDER BY length DESC, col_p1 DESC, col_p2 DESC 
# equivalent to df.sort_values(by =['length',...],ascending=False)
```

5. Finnally:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 col FROM T 
# equivalent to T[:1,'col']
```

where T = is the nested table.

Comment: thank you Beyamina Hamza for giving clear step by step guidance, appreciate your comment.